# Correct way to setState a property of nested object with array properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, jsx

Good day! I have a nested state with array children, and I would like to know the correct and best way to setState.

Here's a sample state object. 
**EDITED**, Forgot to mention that `lists` is an `array of objects`.

```
this.state = {
     lists:
          [{

               name: 'sampleList',
               id: 15,
               permission: {
                    canRead: true,
                    canWrite: false
               }
          }]
     }
}
```

I use this to setState of the permission's properties but the state is not updated.

```
this.setState({
     ...this.state, lists: {
          ...this.state.lists, key: [
               ...this.state.lists.key, permission : {
                    ...this.state.lists.key.permission, 
                    canRead: !this.state.lists.key.permission.canRead
               }
          ] 
     }
 });
```

I hope you can help me. Thanks!

Comment: In setState you are using object {...this.state.list} and not [...this.state.lists] this is problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a copy of the `lists` array, and then replace the object of the index you want to change with a copy of that same object but where you change the `permission`.

**Example**

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    lists: [
      {
        name: "sampleList",
        id: 15,
        permission: {
          canRead: true,
          canWrite: false
        }
      }
    ]
  };

  updateList = (index, canRead, canWrite) => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      const lists = [...prevState.lists];
      lists[index] = { ...lists[index], permission: { canRead, canWrite } };
      return { lists };
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => this.updateList(0, false, true)}>
          Update state
        </button>
        <div>{JSON.stringify(this.state)}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Hi @Tholle, thank you for your answer. This worked for me though I've made some updates on it to satisfy my goal. Thank you again.

Comment: I wonder, what if you don’t know the index, and instead, you have an “id.” Would you use `findIndex` first?

Answer (score 1):

The way to change a specific element of the array with `setState` is to copy all items of array as they are without changing, except for the target item, this can be done with `.map` and `if` statement:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            lists: [
                {
                    name: 'sampleList',
                    id: 15,
                    permission: {
                        canRead: true,
                        canWrite: false
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }

    invertCanRead(targetId) {
        this.setState({
            ...this.state,
            lists: this.state.lists.map(list => {
                if (list.id === targetId) {
                    // that is the one we want to modify, so let's return
                    // modified version:
                    return {
                        ...list,
                        permission: {
                            ...list.permission,
                            canRead: !list.permission.canRead
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    // else return list as is without changes because
                    // it's not the one we want to modify, so just copy it:
                    return list;
                }
            })
        })
    }

    render() {
        return <div>
            {JSON.stringify(this.state)};
            <button onClick={() => this.invertCanRead(15)}></button>
        </div>
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @ilonacodes, the first answer is cleaner for me. Thank you for the effort still, it did give me ideas.